# Distinct number of XORs

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, binary, xor

Given:

two *binary* strings **x** and **y** of the same length; reorder the characters of **x** in an `arbitrary` way and reorder the characters of **y** also in an `arbitrary` *(not necessarily the same)* way.

What is the total number of distinct XOR obtained?

Note:

```
if x = 1 and y = 11 in binary then take x = 01 So,that length of x and y are equal
```

Example:

```
if x = 0 and y = 10
```

then possible outcomes is 2 that is 2 distinct XOR are possible

```
"00" XOR "10" is "10"
"00" XOR "01" is "01"
"00" XOR "10" is "10"
"00" XOR "01" is "01"
```

Comment: Please tell about your desire output with an example. And please share what you have done so far because it will be very helpful for you as well as for community.

Comment: You were asking others to solve a live programming contest problem for you: https://www.codechef.com/DEC19B/problems/BINXOR, while the contest was still open.  That's cheating.  Don't do that.

Comment: But i want to say that i did not particpate in that contest.I have asked only to confrom my method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you're after:

### Code:

```
def f(x, y):
    # Convert integers to string
    x, y = str(x), str(y)

    # Pad inputs
    x, y = x.zfill(max(len(x), len(y))), y.zfill(max(len(x), len(y)))

    rv = set()
    for x_comb in set(''.join(perm_x) for perm_x in itertools.permutations(x)):
        for y_comb in set(''.join(perm_y) for perm_y in itertools.permutations(y)):
            rv.add(f"{x_comb} XOR {y_comb} is {int(x_comb,2) ^ int(y_comb,2):b}")

    return list(rv)
```

### Example usage:

```
>>> f(0, 10)
['00 XOR 01 is 1', '00 XOR 10 is 10']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try computing different number of possible strings as (m+n)!/m!n! where m and n are the no of zeroes and 1 then find try finding a pattern like when strings are same and are different and reach a solution